# Relational databases that do or don't have a schema/namespace layer

Tags: relational-database

In a database system such as MySQL, there is no 'Schema' layer between the Database and table, so the hierarchical layout looks something like this:

- Cluster (MySQL):

  - Database1

    - Table1
    - Table2
  - Database2

    - Table1
    - Table2

However in something like Postgres it contains three levels:

- Cluster (Postgres):

  - Database1

    - Schema1

      - Table1
      - Table2
    - Schema2

      - Table1
      - Table2
  - Database2

    - ...

Is there a listing or comparison of the structure of common relational database engines that show which ones have a two-level hierarchy (such as MySQL) and which ones have a three-level hierarchy (such as Postgres)?

Comment: So In Postgres you can have two same-named tables within a single Database, providing they're in different Schemas? Whereas in MySQL you could put a different prefix on the name of the tables? What's declared in a Postgres Schema? And (how) can you declare that in MySQL?

Comment: SQL is supposed to be a standard. Then one of these vendors is offering a non-compliant database engine. Usually in SQL, "Schema" is not a specific artefact/layer in the DBMS, it's what you declare as " the organization of data". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema (That wiki is not all that good, BTW. Also it discusses specifically Oracle 'schema objects', which is something else again.)

Comment: @AntC  SQL is definitely an [ISO/IEC 7095:2016 Standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/63555.html), ANSI since the 1980's.  The freeware & Oracle are not SQL-compliant, their use of the term is fraudulent.  Of that non-compliant lot, MySQL is the least non-compliant & best in class based on several criteria, Postgres is the most non-compliant, often using SQL terms to mean non-SQL features, as evidenced in this instance.  The worst in class.  The academics deny SQL, and promote their weird "sql"; they deny SQL platforms, and promote Postgres because they created it.

Comment: The SQL `SCHEMA` was defined decades ago.  Therefore the new Postgres `SCHEMA` is anti-SQL, like many things in Postgres.